# WPF/MVVM : How to bind model to view/viewmodel from ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5, mvvm-light

I have an ItemsControl bound to a list of `Tasks`. And I would like to give that model `Task` to its view `TaskView` and viewmodel `TaskViewModel`.

I have try to bind values on the view property like that :

```
<views:TaskView Model="{Binding}" />
```

And then bind the values between the view and the view model :

```
public partial class TaskView
{
    public TaskView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Attempt to bind view.IdProperty with viewmodel.Id
        var binding = new Binding("Id");
        SetBinding(IdProperty, binding);
    }

    public Task Model
    {
        get { return GetValue(ModelProperty) as Task; }
        set { SetValue(ModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(Task), typeof(TaskView));
}
```

However it does not work. Since I'm a newbie in C#/.NET, I have no clue whether I'm in the right direction or not, because it seems to be complicated for a common problem IMO.

*Note that it properly renders the list of tasks, so ItemsControl works as expected.*

Questions :

1. How to build a view from a datasource and pass a model to that view? (Problem explained above)
2. How to read values from that model to the view? (See TaskView.xaml)
3. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing that?

---

Here are the key parts :

**Model**

```
namespace Models
{
  public class Task
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    // And other properties ...
  }    
}
```

**List (parent)**

ViewModel

```
public class ListViewModel : ActionViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Tasks"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tasks, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:Task">
            <!-- TODO : Bind model to task view/viewmodel -->
            <views:TaskView Model="{}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Task (child)**

TaskView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TaskView
{
    public TaskView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Task Model
    {
        get { return GetValue(ModelProperty) as Task; }
        set { SetValue(ModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(Task), typeof(TaskView));
}
```

TaskView.xaml

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels.TaskViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <Border>
      <!-- TODO : Read model attributes -->
      <Grid Background="{Binding Path=Model.Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusBackgroundColourConverter}}">
          <!-- ... -->
      </Grid>
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

TaskViewModel

```
class TaskViewModel : ActionViewModelBase
{
    public Task Model { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe I just don't recognize the pattern you are using, but speaking MVVM, shouldn't you create the viewmodel from the model and the view from the viewmodel instead of having the view cope with with model?

Comment: @grek40 That does not look correct to me. According to the MVVM pattern, the Model should not have knowledge about the ViewModel and the ViewModel should not know about View. See image taken from the MSDN doc https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC564167.png

Comment: Look at the picture and realize, there is no direct connection between view and model. True, the model doesn't know about the viewmodel, but: the viewmodel knows about the model, so it is legal to say something like `new viewmodel(modelData)`. It's similar with viewmodel and view.

Comment: @grek40 I agree, but it seems to be in contradiction with your first comment or I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model and view model parts are defined correctly, however you may want to have a look at the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (to enable two-way databinding to your model).

The view model is automatically passed to your user control via the `DataContext` property (see: [Property Value Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
<DataTemplate DataType="models:Task">
    <!-- DataContext of TaskView is a single Task -->
    <views:TaskView />
</DataTemplate>
```

You must not specify the `DataContext` explicitly in the `UserControl`, as this would overwrite the inherited `DataContext` (and set it to a new instance of `TaskViewModel`).

```
<UserControl x:Class="TaskView">  
  <!-- DataContext of UserControl is a single Task (inherited) -->
  <Border>
      <Grid Background="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusBackgroundColourConverter}}">
          <!-- ... -->
      </Grid>
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: By having the model as a DataContext, I can read the properties (Status and Id). In other words, it works.
However, my ViewModel does not receive Commands anymore. I guess the View and the ViewModel are not linked anymore.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the ViewModel as a DataContext for the View and the Model as a "DataContext" for the ViewModel instead? Or something like that.

Comment: In that case you would need to rename `Task` to `TaskModel`, and introduce a class `TaskViewModel` that has a `Task` property. Then put instances of `TaskViewModel` in your `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: That would be the full MVVM approach, then you could place your commands in the `TaskViewModel` class.

Comment: It works! Simple and straightforward, just the way I like it! :) Though, I've been told that we should not instantiate ViewModels like that, but personally I'm more than happy with this solution.